# Do the various caches in Docker on Mac get corrupted?

Tags: docker

I am trying to troubleshoot a Dockerfile I found on the web. As it is failing in a weird way, I am wondering whether failed docker builds or docker runs from various subsets of that file or other files that I have been experimenting with might corrupt some part of Docker's own state.

In other words, would it possibly help to restart Docker itself, Reboot the computer, or do some other Docker command, to eliminate that possibility?

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes just rebooting things helps and it's not wrong to try restarting Docker for Mac or do a full reboot, but I can't think of a specific symptom it would fix and it's not something I need to do routinely.

I've only really run into two classes of problems that sound like what you're describing.

If you have a Dockerfile step that consistently succeeds, but produces inconsistent results:

```
RUN curl http://may.not.exist.example.com/ || true
```

You can wind up in a situation where the underlying command failed or produced the wrong output, but the `RUN` step as a whole succeeded.  `docker build --no-cache` will re-run a build ignoring this, and an extremely aggressive `docker rmi` sequence (deleting every build, current and past, of the image in question) will clean it up too.

The other class of problem I've encountered involves some level of corruption in `/var/lib/docker`.  This usually has very obvious symptoms generally involving "file not found" or "failed mounting directory" type errors on a setup that you otherwise *know* works.  I've encountered it more on native Linux than Docker for Mac, probably because the DfM Linux installation is a little more controlled and optimized for Docker (it definitely isn't running a 3-year-old kernel with arbitrary vendor patches).  On Linux you can work around this by stopping Docker, deleting everything in `/var/lib/docker`, and starting Docker again; in Docker for Mac, on the preferences window, there's a "Reset" page with various destructive cleanup options and "Reset to factory defaults" is closest to this.

Answer (score 1):

I would first attempt using the Docker 'Diagnose and Feedback option. This generally runs tests on the health of Docker and the Docker engine.

Docker desktop also has options for various troubleshooting scenarios under 'Preferences' > 'Reset' (if you're using Docker Desktop) which have helped me in the past.

A brief look through the previous Docker Release notes.
It certainly looks like it has been possible in the past to corrupt the Docker Engine; there is evidence suggesting the engine has been iteratively fixed since.

Comment: it sounds like you've encountered mysterious problems too and found that resetting docker helped sometimes. Is that a common occurence?

Comment: Docker is super new (and super awesome) and perhaps I got into it too early as a lot has changed over the years. I have certainly run into scenarios where a 'Factory Reset' was required but things are definitely getting more resilient. Which platform are you running on and if you're comfortable sharing perhaps I could take a look at the Dockerfile you refer to?

Comment: I am on Mac and I am very comfortable sharing my Dockerfile. I've been struggling getting a specific scenario to work and I have come to 99% and then it doesn't do what I want it to do. I think SO would frown on using this thread as a discussion, so would you be willing to take to a chat?